# How to convert Schedule to APScheduler module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, apscheduler

I'm a python newbie and need a little help with my code.

I need to convert my code to use APSCHEDULER and not SCHEDULE module because I need to use hours, minutes, seconds which SCHEDULE is not capable of. How can I convert this script to use hh:mm:ss ?

Note: I did read the documentation and examples, and oddly enough there isn't anything about scheduling a job to run at exactly 7:45:30 PM. All the examples appeared to be geared towards cron jobs running every seconds=3.

Here is my code for schedule-module

```
import subprocess
import time
import schedule


def job1():

    subprocess.call("netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenaddress=192.168.0.153 listenport=1101 connectaddress=192.168.0.153 connectport=809 protocol=tcp", shell=True)


def job2():

    subprocess.call("netsh interface portproxy reset", shell=True)


schedule.every().day.at("06:00").do(job1)

schedule.every().day.at("07:00").do(job2)
```